# Spacing in listoffigures with alphabetic chapter

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, chapters

At the end of my document I need a last chapter with seperate numbering for 
additional data. To do this I changed the chapter number to display an **A** via `\setcounter{chapter}{0} \renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}` 
The chapter itself consists of only figures, so I easily get a two digit format like `A.xx.`. In the `listoffigures` the space between the figure number and the caption text disappears for two digit numbers. Every other caption in the document (including the Arabic numbered ones with two digits) is normal as there is a space. Is there a way to add an additional space to the figure number?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[abstracton, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, twoside, BCOR=5mm]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}

\chapter{A Text}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the KOMA-Script class scrreprt you can use the option `listof=flat` to get

[image]

Note that this needs an additional run.

Code:

```
\documentclass[abstract=on, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, twoside, BCOR=5mm,
listof=flat% <- added
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{A Text}
\begin{figure}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\end{figure}

\appendix% <- instead \setcounter{chapter}{0}\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}

\chapter{A Text}
\begin{figure}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\caption{A Text.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

Another possibility is changing the width for the figure numbers manually:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}}
\makeatother
```

The first argument contains the level of the entry, the second sets the indent and the third is the width of the number. The original value of the third argument set by `scrreprt` is `2.3em`.

Comment: The solution worked as far, but a minor problem is ocurring: after introducing `\appendix` the chapters, sections and subsections get an additional dot after the chapter number which I want to get rid off

Comment: To ensure that there will be no dot at the end of the numbers use the option `numbers=noenddot`.